# In App Purchase blocked by "Can't Connect to the Store"

Tags: xcode, itunes-store

Recently, my devices throw an error "Cannot connect to the Store" when I attempt to make an in app purchase. Note that the error doesn't say "iTunes store" or "App store". This was working two days ago, no code has changed.  The only thing I have fiddled with is scheme settings and build settings.  The error arose after I started archiving and building for release.  I do not recall every change I made and am really asking if there is any scheme settings that would cause this issue.

*What I have tried:*

A different device. (Same error, two different devices, on different test user accounts)

A different account/test user.

Not logged in when making the purchase.

Note: The simulator gets passed this error but I need to test this on a device before I publish to the app store.  I can navigate the store just fine with both test user accounts.

Comment: Additionally, the prices are now replaced with "no price".  Could this have anything to do with the timing of the iOS 6 release?

Comment: the release date is for sept 19th not today

Comment: Sorry, not the release, the annoucement, the new NDA to sign, and the developer version?

Comment: It is possible - i just test the in-app purchase on my app; it works fine. Are you still experimenting the same issue?

Comment: Yes I still cannot get the prices to display and purchases return a "Cannot connect to iTunes store" error.

Comment: So you are saying you can't retrieve your product info list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't test in-app purchase in a simulator: see in the first note of this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1).

I think the problem you are facing is not due to your program if it was working previously: the sandbox server used to simulate in-app purchase with your tester account might just be down: in a sandbox environment you don't test your purchase with the real in-app purchase server.

Note that as you certainly have a class that conform to the `SKProductsRequestDelegate`. You can implement the `request:didFailWithError:` to get a notification when you fail to get the product info list.